# How to prevent removing "section" from <div contenteditable> when editing?

Tags: javascript, dom, contenteditable

How to prevent a user from removing <section> inside <div contenteditable> editor during editing (at least by pressing "Delete"/"Backspace" keys)?

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <style>
  #editor {
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
   border: 1px black solid;
  }
  #dont-remove-me-please{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px red dashed;
   font-weight: bold;
   user-select: none;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="app"></div>

 <div contenteditable="true" id="editor">
  <div>hey guys!</div>
  <div><strong>more text...</strong></div>
  <section id="dont-remove-me-please" contenteditable="false">DONT' REMOVE ME!!!</section>
  <div><br></div>
 </div>
 <script>
  document.getElementById('editor').focus()
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank You.

Comment: How to prevent it's removal?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Yes. Section must not be removed in my example during editing. At least I need to know how to prevent deletion of section via delete/backspace keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `contenteditable=false` to children to prevent them from being editable.

However if you still want the children to be editable but the child dom elements shouldn't be removable I think you need to listen to backspace/delete events and see how these effect the dom and undo the changes if they remove dom nodes. Trying to figure this out myself

Edit: this is what I did

```
function onpaste(e: ClipboardEvent) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const selection = window.getSelection();
  // Don't allow deleting nodes
  if (selection.anchorNode.isSameNode(selection.focusNode)) {
    // get text representation of clipboard
    const text = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");

    // insert text manually, but without new line characters as can't support <br/>s yet
    document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, text.replace(/\n/g, ""));
  }
}

function onkeydownInEditable(e: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (e.key === "Backspace" || e.key === "Delete" || e.key === "Paste") {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    // Don't allow deleting nodes
    if (!selection.anchorNode.isSameNode(selection.focusNode))
      e.preventDefault();
  }
}

 elementEditing.addEventListener("keydown", onkeydownInEditable);
 elementEditing.addEventListener("paste", onpaste);
```

Answer (score -1):

To achieve expected result, use below click event listener and add contenteditable attribute based on id

```
<script>
        document.getElementById('editor').addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
                     if(e.target.id !=="dont-remove-me-please"){
                         e.target.setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
                     }
                  }, false);
    </script>
```

code sample - https://codesandbox.io/s/rypy7wkn5m

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <style>
  #editor {
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
   border: 1px black solid;
  }
  #dont-remove-me-please{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px red dashed;
   font-weight: bold;
   user-select: none;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>

 <div id="app"></div>

 <div id="editor">
  <div>hey guys!</div>
  <div><strong>more text...</strong></div>
  <section id="dont-remove-me-please" contenteditable="false">DONT' REMOVE ME!!!</section>
  <div><br></div>
 </div>
 <script>
  document.getElementById('editor').focus()
 </script>
  <script>
   document.getElementById('editor').addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
       if(e.target.id !=="dont-remove-me-please"){
        e.target.setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
       }
       }, false);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. But other divs have to be editable all the time. Moreover, user may remove empty strings -> join divs...

Comment: create class and use that class to loop through elements by ClassName and addEventlistener - https://codesandbox.io/s/rypy7wkn5m